# In custom wordpress responsive theme bootstrap.ss overlap style.css

Tags: css, responsive-design

On creating a custom theme i faced one problem http://templategraphy.com/wp-demo/landro/
lookwise its not look so good because it not supported style.css By default it shows all its css properties from bootstrap.min.css.

I want theme look good like this html http://templategraphy.com/demo/landro/ what should i do so that theme take all its css properties from style.css.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to define a Child Theme if you are using any themes. A child theme will allow you to make subtle changes to an existing theme but if you upgrade your theme the changes will remain. Your situation: Within your child theme you can override Bootstrap styles by using `!important` for some of the styles that aren't working. Don't use `!important` too much, however.

Comment: thanks chris for your suggestions. but i am not using any !important in bootstarp.mim.css i am not too much friendly to css so please can u explain me again what exactly i do so that theme look perfect..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you first need to link bootstrap.css and then your style.css

cause in css order is important for cascading.

all custom styles or created by you comes last.

Comment: thnks maulik its working... please check my theme http://templategraphy.com/wp-demo/landro/ now it shows menus getting disordered form.portfolio menu shifted on

Comment: `#nav-section .container #nav-menu li {
float: left;
margin-right: 42px;
}`  this rule in style.css ,causing portfolio to shift down